# Loop over columns with df.shift in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say you have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df

    A   B
0   3   5
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
```

Now I want to skew and calculate on each column. I put the values as I want them skewed in the index:

```
range_span = range(4)
result = pd.DataFrame(index=range_span)
```

Then I try to pupulate result with the following:

```
for c in df.columns:
    for i in range_span: 
        result.iloc[i][c] = df[c].shift(i).max()
          
result
```

This only returns the index. I expected something like this:
[image]

Comment: ```range_span``` is already ```range``` object, seems like you made typo in 3rd code - ```range(range_span)``` will raise ```TypeError```.

Comment: Thank. Fixed it, but the result is still an empty dataframe.

Comment: I'm also wondering why, still tinkering with it - but google didn't give me clear meaning of database `skewing`. Might have to change Question title to have that word in it if question is not just about iterating thru columns in nested loop.

Comment: According to IBM *skew* is  uneven distribution of data, but I'm having trouble understanding expected output - Is there other meaning on word *skew*?

Comment: Maybe wrong word. what I mean is to shift the data down. Like the expression in the script (df.shift(i)). If you have a dataframe and run df.column.shift[1] the whole column get shifted/pushed (or skewed as I call it) one row down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 critical issues:

---

#### issue #1

At this line

```py
result.iloc[i][c] = df[c].shift(i).max()
```

Raises warning that help understand why `result` is empty.

> ...\pandas\core\indexing.py:670: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a ***copy of a slice*** from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

According to their document:

```py
dfmi['one']['second'] = value
# becomes
dfmi.__getitem__('one').__setitem__('second', value)
```

As `iloc[i]` will return `slice` - aka *copy* - of that rows, you couldn't set original dataframe `result`. Further, this is why `iloc` didn't raised issue when it got `str` index. Explained in #2.

Instead you use `iloc` - potentially `loc` with `str` - like  this:

```py
>>> df
   A   B    C
0  1  10  100
1  2  20  200
2  3  30  300

>>> df.iloc[1, 2]
200

>>>df.iloc[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
    B    C
1  20  200
2  30  300

>>> df.iloc[1:3, 1:3]
    B    C
1  20  200
2  30  300

>>> df.iloc[:, 1:3]
    B    C
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300

# ..and so on
```

---

#### issue #2

If you fix issue #1 then you'll see following error:

```py
    result.iloc[[i][c]] = df[c].shift(i).max()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Also from their document:

> `property DataFrame.iloc`:  Purely ***integer-location*** based indexing for selection by position.

At `for c in df.columns:` You're passing column name A, B which is `str`, not `int`. Use `loc` instead for `str` column indices.

This didn't raise `TypeError` due to issue #1 - as `c` was passed as argument of `__setitem__()`.

---

#### Issue #3

Normally `dataframe` cannot be enlarged without special functions like `combine`.

```
# using same df from #1
>>> df.iloc[1, 3] = 300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1394, in _has_valid_setitem_indexer
    raise IndexError("iloc cannot enlarge its target object")
IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object
```

Easier fix would be using `dict` and convert to `DataFrame` when manipulation is complete. Or just creating `DataFrame` to match or have a larger size at firsthand:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4), columns=range(3))
>>> df2
     0    1    2
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

Combining all, correct fix would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

result = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

for col in df.columns:
    for index in df.index:
        result.loc[index, col] = df[col].shift(index).max()

print(result)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  3  8
1  3  7
2  3  6
3  3  5
```